# Не могу записать файлы когда вызываю скрипт его через CRON

Tags: php

Не нормально работает [class Simple Image](https://gist.github.com/miguelxt/908143) когда вызываю его через CRON. Работает нормально, только когда вызов идет через браузер

```
   $image = new SimpleImage();
   $image  ->load($path);

   $format_avatar = explode(".", $path);
   $name_photo  = md5(microtime() . $postId). '.' .    $format_avatar[count($format_avatar) - 1];
  $uploaddir_big = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/site.com/images/big/';

 $image -> save($uploaddir_big . $name_photo) // = true, но файлов не обнаруженно
```

**Некоторые функции из класса [class Simple Image](https://gist.github.com/miguelxt/908143)**

```
function load($filename) {
  $image_info = getimagesize($filename);
  $this->image_type = $image_info[2];
  if( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
     $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
  } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
     $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
  } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
     $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
  }
}
   function save($filename, $image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG, $compression=75, $permissions=null) {
  if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
     imagejpeg($this->image,$filename,$compression);
     return 'true';
  } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
     imagegif($this->image,$filename);
     return 'true';
  } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
     imagepng($this->image,$filename);
     return 'true';
  }
  if( $permissions != null) {
     chmod($filename,$permissions);
  }
```

}

Выдает ошибку

> Warning:  imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg]: Unable to open    'site.com/images/big/dfa47b99317704b23660e09de5604dd4.jpg' for writing: No such file or directory in /home/content/90/10541990/html/cron/download_posts.php

Comment: Чему равно это значение:  

    $uploaddir_big . $name_photo)
?

Comment: /var/chroot/home/content/90/10541990/html/site.com/images/big/name.png

Comment: Прав на запись в директорию нет, как и говорится в тексте ошибки.

Comment: в смысле нет ? Фишка в том, что если я вызываю через браузер все ок, а если через CRON то выскакивает эта ошибка

Comment: присвойте директории права 777 и проверьте ещё раз ).  
Как сказал @ReinRaus, у крона может не быть прав на запись в эту директорию. А у веб-сервера есть.

Comment: если в скрипте поставить include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/site.com/common_use.php';

то будет ошибка 
 include_once(/site.com/common_use.php) [<a href='function.include-once'>function.include-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/home/content/90/10541990/html/site.com/download_posts.php</b> on line <b>2</b><br />

Comment: @Zow, вы как-то странно слушаете ответы... Вам же говорят: проверьте права!

Крон от чьего имени запускается? Скорее всего от вашего. А когда скрипт через браузер запущен - скорее всего от имени www-data.

Значит в эти папки для www-data доступ на запись есть, а для вас - нет. Как-то так.

Сделайте в консоли:

    chmod -R a+w /var/chroot/home/content/90/10541990/html/site.com/images/

и проверьте еще раз

Comment: `$uploaddir_big = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` cron про это ничего не знает. как-нибудь по-другому указывайте директорию сайта.

Comment: Точно! Например, использовать вместо этого `__DIR__`

Comment: там путь `/home/content/90/10541990/html/cron/download_posts.php` так-что не очень ясно где там именно этот site.com я бы вообще в таком случае не парился, а вызывал cron'ом curl на этот cron.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

то, что вы запускаете через web работает относительно рута сайта, крон работает относительно файловой системы, возможно из-за этого проблема - попробуйте использовать везде абсолютные пути файловой системы а не серверные переменные

Answer (score 2):

При работе с кроном пользуюсь всегда таким кодом:

```
if (in_array(strtolower(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])),Array('php','php.exe'))) {
  $mod_path=dirname($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);  // Исполняемый файл
}else{
  $mod_path=dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
}
// Переход в каталог скрипта
if ($mod_path!=getcwd()) @chdir($mod_path);
```

Вставляется в начале скрипта.